# ExtJS grid-like custom control

Tags: extjs, widget, custom-controls

I need to implement grid like control that utilizes some complex custom widgets for viewing and displaying rows. Just like this one:

[image]

The key point here is that controls in the right column depend on the value selected in the combobox from the left column.

Does anyone know what is the best way to implement it using ExtJS 5.0 components? Should I create my own widgets to display row data that will serve as both custom renderers and editors?

Answer (score 0):

I would use a [`beforeedit`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.3/#!/api/Ext.grid.plugin.CellEditing-event-beforeedit) function which changes the editor of the right column ([`setEditor`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.3/#!/api/Ext.grid.column.Column-method-setEditor)) to the required widget type depending on what is set in the left column. If you use Editing (RowEdit) plugin instead of CellEditing, you would also have to setEditor in the left column's `change` or `select` event.

This is the easiest way, but it won't show all editors at once, of course.

To have all editors displayed at once, I would make a new field containing multiple fields. You can add multiple instances of these fields to a fieldset, container, panel or form at runtime.